# Is this analysis correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning

1. Who doesn't hear this and not get bored?
   = Whoever hears this does not get bored.
2. Who doesn't hear this and get excited?
   = Whoever hears this gets excited.

Thus, Sentences 1 and 2 convey essentially the same meaning.

Comment: It's correct that they mean the same, but (1) is a rather convoluted way to say it.

Comment: Double-negatives don't often avoid not sounding good.